# Can I change the input data at each epoch when i use tf.estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, object-detection-api

I'm implementing new data augmentation strategies for the Tensorflow Object Detection Api and I want to support schedule of augmentation which depend on the current training epoch.

The idea (from https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05393) is :

- epoch 1: perform augmentation_A + augmentation_B
- epoch 2: perform augmentation_C + augmentation_B
- epoch 3: perform augmentation_D
- ...

How can I change the input data at each epoch when I use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate` ?

I have augmention functions in my `train_input_fn` but it's fixed and they are used in the same way at each epoch.

```py
...
#train_input_fn perform augmentations on my input data
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, ...)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn)

#Object detection Api use train_and_evaluate to train the model
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_specs)
```

Is it possible to update the `train_spec` during the training and give the current epoch as argument to my `train_input_fn` ? Or do you see another way to do it ?